# How to get rows that has certain columns containing same values using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a users table where the clients can either register themselves or call the company to register them in case the process is complicated for them, i wanted to organize the clients list in order to have: the self registered clients in one page ,and the clients registered by an employee in another page, my application is using Laravel/MySQL, but the query was too complicated for me to do it by myself

Here is what I have tried using eloquent:

```
$clients = User::where([['role','Client'],['created_by','id']])->get();
```

This query is meant to select rows that have been created by the same person in another words: if I registered myself through the form my row will look like this :

```
id: 1
created_by:1
```

but this query didn't work.

I could select all the rows and do an if test for each row in my view but that's not optimal and seem like cheating, I want to be able to understand the perfect solution in MySQL. In order to develop my skills.

Comment: Wouldn't `['created_by','id']` look for data that has _the string_ `id` as `created_by`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereColumn`, which is describe in the [Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) section in laravels documentation.
And for the `role` you use a normal `where`.

```
$clients = User::where('role', 'Client')->whereColumn('created_by', 'id')->get();
```

With your code you're searching for a User where `created_by` has the value `id`.

Comment: perfect it worked for me thank you so much, do you know by any chance the solution in mysql ? just to learn more, because i didn't find the answere in mysql also

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE role = 'Client' AND created_by = id;`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$clients = User::where(['role'=>'Client','created_by'=>'id'])->get();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.